# Insert data into table where the id column should increment with latest id value from same table without using identity

Tags: sql-server, select, insert, primary-key

I have a table temp1 where I have all the data and now I need to insert values into another table "temp", where the id column in "temp" should get incremented by a value because there is another identity column in temp.

```
temp(id int primay key,name varchar(100),sql_identity int having identity)
temp1(name varchar(100))
```

When I am trying to use the following code

```
set @inc = 10
insert into temp 
select (select coalesce(max(id),0) + @inc from temp), name
from temp1
```

I got following error in SQL Server:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 4
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__temp__3213E83F7C06E24B'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.temp'. The duplicate key value is (10).
>   The statement has been terminated.

Ideally in temp table data should be in following manner:

```
 id | name
 1  | val1
 2  | val2
 3  | val3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to roll your own auto-increment mechanism in SQL - It's bound to fail.

Instead, use the built-in constructs SQL Server provides.
If you already have an identity column on the table, and you need another identity-like column, your best bet would be to use a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and let SQL Server handle the numbering.

Create a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.SampleSequence
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 10 ;  
GO
```

And use it as the default value of the column:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Temp
(  
    Id int 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Temp PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
        CONSTRAINT DF_Temp_Id DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SampleSequence),  
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
    sql_identity int NOT NULL identity(1,1),
) ;
```

Please note that using a sequence, much like using identity, does not guarantee continuous numbering, nor uniqueness of values (it will be unique as long is it's not tempered with, though).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your table temp1 has many records , that's why you get an Error like that.

```
set @inc = 10

insert into temp 
(
    id ,name 
)
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)+(select coalesce(max(id),0) + @inc from temp), name 
from temp1
```